# What is a Cryptobackup file? Cannot delete folder because of access denied to a cryptobackup file

Tags: permissions, pdf-generation, system, user-permissions

When I tried to delete a folder, I was encountered with the routine error message that some files in this folder are in use and you cannot delete it. After playing with the files I found out that none of the main files were causing the problem. But there was a  file which was hidden and cannot be deleted. Apparently that file is not a virus and it is in fact the Cryptobackup of an already pdf file previously in the folder. I tried a lot of things but couldn't delete it because the system says access is denied to this file. Even tried to delete it from a command line run by administrator. But not successful.

[image]
The funny thing is that now that I have seen hidden files (especially protected system files), I have realized there are a lot of Cryptobackup files which are the backups of pdf files I have generated before. But I can delete them. But this one cannot be deleted. Weird.

P.S. Could someone with reputation higher than 1500 create the new tag `cryptobackup` please?! I think it could be helpful for others too. Thanks.

Comment: Do you using java or which way do you using for try to delete this file?

Comment: I wonder if it might be a file backup in the case of ransomware, like a backup encryption file, or maybe the other way around, ransomware crypto file so that when the ransomware encrypts your file it has a backup in the case you want it back? Just wondering.